# Jade - Include var from an external js file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

Jade newbie here.

I'm aware that in Jade you are allowed to create js variables and interpolate them in seamlessly with html like so:

```
- var myname = "john"
p my name is #{myname}
```

However what if that variable were to come from an external .js file (or, if impossible, an external .jade file)?

file.js:

```
var myname = "john";
```

and then the index.jade:

```
- include file.js
p my name is #{myname} //this does not work
```

I'm not sure whether the `render` function has anything to do with this. If someone could be so generous as to explain this in plain English, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`include` just includes the raw text if the file is not a Jade file. [More info](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/)

So `- include file.js` wouldn't parse any of it's content.

It should work for another Jade file though.

Comment: That's interesting, so theoretically if I include another Jade file that uses those variables it should work?

Answer (score 0):

I think what most people do is to throw in variable:value pairs at the call to render:

```
  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { myname: 'John' });
  });
```

...and then use them as inline variables as you did earlier.

Comment: The code I showed above is usually in your router code, the part that decides to render 'index' in this case if the person asks for '/'.  And then in your 'index.jade' it could refer to just... "p my name is #{myname}" and it would write "John" there as you did before.